# the head section of the panel is not collapsing while the body collaps

Tags: jquery, html, css

im building a chat interface and i have the ability to make chat boxes to for each client.the problem is when i try to minimize a tag while the another tag is open it works in a wired way

how to make the minimized chat box tags go to the bottom of the parent instead of the top
single chat box open

[image]

single chat box minimized[image]

two chat boxes open(dont worry about margins between the two chat boxes)

[image]

**the issue** one chat box open and the other minimized

[image]

if the two panels are minimized it looks normal

[image]

here is the story

the chat boxes are in a div which is fixed to the window bottom and the message boxes are floated to the right.

i have added a red background so the parent div is visiblere is the meaasge box code

```js
        $(document.body).on("click", ".msg_head", function (event) {
            $(event.target).parent().find('.msg_wrap').slideToggle('slow');
        });


        $(document.body).on("click", ".closechat", function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).parents()[1].remove();
        });
```

```css
.chat_container{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right: 290px;
}
.msg_head{
    background:#3498db;
}

.msg_body{
    background:white;
    height:200px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:15px;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.msg_input{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.closechat{
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.minimize{
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-right:5px;

}
```

```html
<div style="  position:fixed; bottom:0px;right: 290px;background-color: red;">
    <div class="chat_container" style="">
    <div class="msg_box" style="float: right;position: relative;" data-eid="8">
        <div class="msg_head">vikum vikum
            <div class="closechat">x</div>
        </div>
        <div class="msg_wrap" style="display: block;">
            <div class="msg_body">
                <div class="msg_push"></div>
            </div>
        <div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    

    <div class="msg_box" style="float: right;position: relative;" data-eid="7">
        <div class="msg_head">Shalitha Shalitha
            <div class="closechat">x</div>
        </div>
        <div class="msg_wrap" style="display: block;">
            <div class="msg_body">
                <div class="msg_push"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4" style="margin: 0px; width: 280px; height: 68px;"></textarea></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add these lines to the onclick event , it will work like a charm ;)

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".msg_head", function (event) {
        var $msgbox = $(event.target).parent();
        $msgbox.find('.msg_wrap').slideToggle('slow');
        $msgbox.animate({'padding-top':$msgbox.find('.msg_wrap').height()},'slow');

    });
```